# Найти доминирующий цвет | KMeans | Emgu.CV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Как с помощью библиотеки Emgu.CV можно найти доминирующий цвет изображения?

Я знаю про функцию [`CvInvoke.KMeans(...)`](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/7debc320-32f5-4632-a527-498d5f01f925.htm), в которую можно передать исходное изображение `Image<..., float>` и количество ожидаемых цветов `k`. У неё есть 2 аргумента "на выход": `bestLables` и `centers` - 2 `Mat`-объекта. Но я никак не могу понять: как из этих `Mat` получить массив цветов, по типу `MCvScalar[]`.

Код, для быстрого воспроизведения:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;

using var image   = new Bitmap(filepath).ToImage<Bgr, float>();
using var labels  = new Mat();
using var centers = new Mat();

CvInvoke.Kmeans(resultImage, 5, labels, new MCvTermCriteria(10, 0.0001), 2, KMeansInitType.PPCenters, centers);
```

Comment: На крайняк можно руками в цикле повыдергивать.

Comment: @aepot я б с радостью повыдёргивал руками, но не знаю как. Если покажете пример, буду весьма благодарен)

Comment: Ну есть же указатель на данные `Mat.DataPointer`? Можно скопировать в массив, например через `Marshal.Copy` или напрямую подергать. Я уж не знаю, как именно атм данные лежат, но поотлаживать, думаю, реально. Вот, наешл [кое-что похожее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32559496/12888024).

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема, не только в получении значений, а и в том что я не понимаю что означает матрица центров, если бы я это понимал, то придумал бы способ переделать в нужный вид